# Page not reloading in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am facing route dom error. category url redirect properly, but content not reloading what I missing could you please let me know your feedback. I mention below
menu.jsx
Link tag url **{x.category_url}** it does change url but it is not changing content of page. App.jsx line Route path="/category/:name/:id" component={CategoriesList}

App.jsx:

```
    // import logo from './logo.svg';
    import './App.css';
    import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
    import CategoriesList from './ComponentList/CategoriesList'; 
    import CustomerReview from './StoreComponent/CustomerReview';
    import Related from './StoreComponent/Related'; 
import Home from './ComponentList/Home'; 
    import Store from './StoreComponent/Store';
    function App() {
      
      // const reload = () => window.location.reload();
      return (
        <BrowserRouter>
    
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
              <Home/>
            </Route>
            
            <Route path="/store/:name/:id" component={Store}>
              <Store/>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/store/:name/:id" component={CustomerReview}>
              <CustomerReview/>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/store/:name/:id" component={Related}>
              <Related/>
            </Route>
            
            <Route path="/category/:name/:id" component={CategoriesList}>
              <CategoriesList/>
            </Route>
           </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
    
    export default App;
Menu.jsx:
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Grid, Image } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
export default class Menu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isLoading: true,
    };
  }
  refreshPage() {
    window.location(false);
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ title: "React POST Request Example" }),
    };

    const url = "http://localhost:3000/api/v4/web/categories";
    fetch(url, requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({ data: json.categories });
        // console.log(json.categories)
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
      });
  }

  render() {
    // console.log(this.pathname)
    return (
      <Grid className="home-icon">
        <Grid.Row centered doubling columns={8} mobile>
          {this.state.data.map((x, i) => (
            <Grid.Column centered key={i}>
              <Link to={x.category_url}>
                <Image src={x.image} alt="" />
              </Link> 
              <Link to={x.category_url}>
                <p>{x.store_name}</p>
              </Link>
            </Grid.Column>
          ))}
        </Grid.Row>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}
 CategoriesList.jsx:
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { withRouter, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Grid, Image, Segment, Card } from "semantic-ui-react";
import TopMenuStrip from "../ComponentList/TopMenuStrip";
import LogoSection from "../ComponentList/LogoSection";
import Footer from "../ComponentList/Footer";
import Menu from "../ComponentList/Menu";
import CopyRight from "../ComponentList/CopyRight";
class CategoriesList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isLoading: true,
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    // console.log(this.props.match.params.id)
    let url_id = this.props.match.params.id;
    console.log("category");
    console.log(url_id);
    const url = "http://localhost:3000/api/v4/web/list";
    const postBody = {
      category_id: url_id,
      offer_type: "",
    };
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(postBody),
    };

    fetch(url, requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({ data: json });
        // console.log('sasasas')
        // console.log(json)
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
      });
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.data.stores) {
      return null;
    }
    const ListStores = this.state.data.stores;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <TopMenuStrip />
        <LogoSection />
        <Menu />
        <Grid className="store-list">
          <Grid.Column width={16}>
            <p>
              <span>{this.state.data.heading_label}</span>
            </p>
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid>
        <Grid columns={4} className="all-offers storeList">
          {ListStores.map((x) => {
            return (
              <Grid.Column>
                <Segment>
                  <Card>
                    <Link to={x.store_url}>
                      {" "}
                      <Image
                        src={x.image}
                        alt=""
                        className="collection-img"
                      ></Image>
                    </Link>
                    <Card.Content>
                      <Link to={x.store_url}>
                        {" "}
                        <Card.Header>{x.name}</Card.Header>
                      </Link>
                      <Card.Description>{x.store_summary}</Card.Description>
                    </Card.Content>
                    <Card.Content extra>
                      <p className="rewards">
                        <span>
                          <img src="/images/rewards.png" alt=""></img>
                        </span>
                        Cash rewards upto <span>AED {x.cashback}</span>
                      </p>
                      <p className="location">
                        <span>
                          <img src="/images/location.png" alt=""></img>
                        </span>

                        {x.store_branches.map((locations, index) => (
                          <span className="store-location">
                            {index === 0 ? (
                              <span>{locations.store_location}</span>
                            ) : index >= 1 ? (
                              <span>
                                ,&nbsp;&nbsp;{locations.store_location}
                              </span>
                            ) : null}
                          </span>
                        ))}
                      </p>
                    </Card.Content>
                  </Card>
                </Segment>
              </Grid.Column>
            );
          })}
        </Grid>
        <Footer />
        <CopyRight />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
export default withRouter(CategoriesList);
```

Comment: You are rendering three routes with identical paths, `"/store/:name/:id"`, so the first one rendering `Store` will be matched and rendered by the `Switch`. You are also rendering both on the `component` prop and passing children to your routes, only choose one rendering method in the `Route`. What and were is rendering `Menu` component?

Comment: This is /store/:name/:id/ working fine, not reload this category/:name/:id please provide some code

Comment: What is rendering the `Menu` component where the links aren't working?

Comment: I rendered menu component on this <Link to={x.category_url}> <Image src={x.image} alt="" /> </Link> redirect working but page content not change.

Comment: Where is `Menu` rendered there? That is a link with an `Image` component. What is value of `x.category_url` for link's `to` prop?

Comment: x.category_url value of  category/fashion/19

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234356/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-user5561847).

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

The `CategoriesList` component you are linking to is already mounted, so the component isn't responding, or reacting, to the `name` and `id` route match params updating.

## Solution

I am assuming you want/need the same logic that runs on component mount to also be run when the component updates. You can refactor this logic into a utility function to be called in `componentDidMount` like you already do, and than also in `componentDidUpdate`.

```
getData = () => {
  const { id } = this.props.match.params;
  
  const url = "http://localhost:3000/api/v4/web/list";
  const postBody = {
    category_id: id,
    offer_type: "",
  };

  const requestOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify(postBody),
  };

  this.setState({ isLoading: true });

  fetch(url, requestOptions)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
      this.setState({ data: json });
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error(error))
    .finally(() => {
      this.setState({ isLoading: false });
    });
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.getData();
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id) {
    this.getData();
  }
}
```